Do cracks in floor tile indicate water damage?
We had a water loss at our house a year and a half ago. The flooding came up to/into this bathroom. In the beginning insurance said the tile was not impacted. Fine. We accepted that.
However, moving back in, we saw that the tile had cracked around the door frame on both sides of the door and the door no longer closes properly. It doesn’t latch. Insurance is telling us there's still no damage and that the cracking is normal, and the door is not closing because the hinges are installed in properly.
However, no one removed the door and it was closing fine before the water loss.
Could there be something else going on? Swollen wood anywhere? What are we missing? We’d like to continue fighting this if there is actual damage happening underneath/on the sides.
Pictures


You need to check the wood under the tiles.  Usually if the the water is removed fast enough and the wood is dried out, there should be no problems.  Usually drying out wood means removing some drywall and.or flooring to let air from fans to it.

Agreed, can you look at the wood under it? Perhaps from below, if it's an unfinished basement or if you can remove some drywall. IT certainly looks like it could be water damage, but it's hard to be sure from just these photos. If you have any doubt, it might help to get a home inspector to take a look.

The separation following the door trim exactly is interesting. It looks like the door was trimmed out then the tile was installed - unusual order of operations. I wonder if OP gain a look at the subfloor if they remove the door trim?

@AdamO the tile was probably installed after words by a diyer. I would have trimmed the doorframe and slipped the tile under it instead of scribing a tile. But I am lazy, don't like cutting tile very much, and think it looks much neater if done that way.

I see no issue with the tile, or cracked tiles as you state.
What is evident is the grout between the tile edge and the door frame and casing is separated from the tile. This is common when wood gets wet and then dries. Normally the door casing would be undercut and the tile slipped under. Your tile was not installed that way.
It is also common that the wood would not go back to its's original shape. It would be twisted or bowed to some degree and this is why there is the separation that you are thinking are cracks. This is also why the door will not close. There must be adjustments made to account for the woods movement.
Generally this is a minor issue and is not an indication of larger underlying problems.  Again I see no cracked tiles.  If there are, you have not prominently displayed them in your pictures. No cracked or loose tiles indicate that the subflooring is stable and without issues.
